# Update a table with previous value from another table php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables :table_a (name ,ID) and table_b(Task).

I have an option to insert values from table_a.name into table_b.Task.

But when I want to delete a value from table_a.name and the value is found in table_b.Task ,then table_b.Task value must be updated with the previous value of the deleted value from table_a.name.

Here is the code:

```
  $delete=$_POST['deletevalue'];
  if(isset($_POST['_submit'])){

$id=mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM table_a WHERE name='$delete'");


$x=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table_a WHERE ID<$id");

$task=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table_a WHERE ID=$x");

$query1=mysql_query("delete from table_a where name='$delete'");

$query2=mysql_query("UPDATE table_b SET Stare='$task' WHERE Task='$delete'");
```

P.S. ID is auto incremeni

When I use this code and display table_b the value that should be updated is blank.
Please help me make it work

Comment: Have you tried to debug anything? What is the actual value of `$id`, `$x` and `$task` inside PHP?

Answer (score 0):

In php, the function mysql_query returns a resultset object.

To fetch the actual value, you need to fetch the value from the resultset. This should help:

```
$objId=mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM table_a WHERE name='$delete'");
$rowId=mysql_fetch_row($objId);
$id=$rowId[0];
```

Similarly, you can get the values for the other instances.

As an aside, you can combine these queries:

```
$id=mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM table_a WHERE name='$delete'");
$x=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table_a WHERE ID<$id");
$task=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table_a WHERE ID=$x");
```

as

```
$objTask=mysql_query("SELECT a.name FROM table_a a WHERE a.ID=(SELECT MAX(b.ID) from table_a b WHERE b.ID<(SELECT c.ID FROM table_a c WHERE c.name='$delete'))");
$rowTask=mysql_fetch_row($objTask);
$task=$rowTask[0];
```

This will fetch the value you require.

EDIT:
Update and delete statements don't generate any resultsets as output.

Comment: I used your code and I got this error:Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: Can you check if the queries mentioned in the original code actually give some output?

Comment: ok but how can I display the result? if I use echo it doesn't show anything....if I use mysql_fetch_array I get the same error.I tried to display and other values not that complicated like : Select x from y where ID=5 and I can't get to display it.I am new to php so sorry for the trouble